# Writing multiple files to one file (like a file system)

Tags: java

I'm trying to store multiple data files that I have created into one file. Each file has an ID# (0-35) and each holds some data. But what I want is to be able to store all the files in one file called 'data.xx', then be able to access the each of the files data inside the data.xx file.

```
public static void pack(int id) {
    try {
        RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile("./data/data.xx", "rw");
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = null;
        try {
            byte[] data = toByteArray(id);
            bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
            raf.seek(raf.length());
            System.out.println(raf.length());
            while (bis.read(data, 0, data.length) >= 0) {
                raf.write(data, 0, data.length);
            }
        } finally {
            bis.close();
            raf.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

toByteArray(id) calls the separate data files then puts it into byte array. All the files seem to write fine to the data.xx file. The problem I'm having is I'm not really sure how to read the data.xx file so I can get the data from the files that are stored in it. I hope this makes sense. Also I don't need any compression and I don't want to use a library for this.

Thank you

Comment: You would need a special token (that no "file" could contain) to separate the file entries. Alternatively, you could start the file with a header block containing a list of all "files" and their lengths (so you could calculate the appropriate offset to the start of the next entry). Of course, you could just write to a [`ZipFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html) which basically does that already (a zip file contains [`ZipEntry`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipEntry.html)(s)).

Comment: Thanks a lot, how could I have not realized something so simple like that.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is use markup:

```
<id_0> content of file 0 </id_0>
...
<id_35> content of file 35 </id_35>
```

You write file like that and read content inside tags with `substring`

Answer (score 0):

I would prepend the output file with the offsets of the start of each contained file. A special "token" is a nice idea, but files can contain any byte or bytes; making the idea not realistic. That way your "index" will terminate with something you can't confuse with file data because the information occurres before you expect arbitrary data ... say, `0`? Please comment if I misunderstood this question.